# image editor using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, image, editor, using

I am looking for an image editor which can be incorporated into my asp.net application ( online shopping project with product custom design).

Our project handling the online shopping with Tape products. user can design his tape model.  like color, text and images or company logos.

like,

---

ABC Private LTD       ABC Private LTD      ABC Private LTD

---

User can able to add the text or image from the tape
User can  able to select the text font color,size and font name
User can  able to add the company logo
and edit it (crop, resize, flip, rotate, etc) and save it

how can we do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

see if the following opensource plugin at codeplex helps [It's here](http://imageeditor.codeplex.com/)

it have the ability to let the end user can crop, resize and edit image.
a live demo is [here](http://www.wesnetdesigns.com/Projects/ImageEditor/tabid/114/Default.aspx)

now i am not sure will it work for simple webforms or not perhaps  it's only targeting Dot Net Nuke project